# Motor still locked after pressing disable all steppers

Tags: marlin, motor

My extruder 1 (IDEX - robin pro board) is locked in position when turning on printer while the other motors are free to move. When I press the disable all steppers button the e0 is still locked while all other steppers are free to move by hand. (When starting a print all motors are still functioning normally) Anyone who knows why or how to fix?